# Correct usage of Promises, Fetch, success/fail handlers

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I want to be sure I'm using Promises correctly. We have the below method to simplify making API requests. I've removed things not necessary, like headers.

The intention here is to return a promise to the caller of makeApiRequest. This is being used in the context of a thunk (specifically [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)) and we want to be able to chain more `.then()` statements.

```
const makeApiRequest = (request, onSuccess = defaultOnSuccess, onFailed = defaultOnFailed) => {
    const CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    const headers = { ... }

    return fetch(request.url, {...}).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json()
                .then((json) => Promise.resolve(onSuccess(response.status, json)))
                .catch((error) => Promise.reject({message: error, status: response.status}))
        }

        const errorResponse = {
            status: response.status,
            message: response.error
        }

        if(response.status === 401) {
            errorResponse.message = 'Unauthorized'
        }
        return Promise.reject(errorResponse)
    }).catch((error) => {
        onFailed(error.status, error.message)
        console.log(error)
    })
}

const defaultOnFailed = (status, error) => console.log([status, error])
const defaultOnSuccess = (status, data) => console.log([status, data])

export default makeApiRequest
```

**Questions**

1) Am I implementing success/fail handlers optimally?

2) I feel like having the nested catch statements is wrong, but I need to be able to deal with errors in context.

Comment: `.then((json) => Promise.resolve(onSuccess(response.status, json)))` you don't need to wrap the result from onSuccess in a Promise.resolve in this case ... any value returned in `.then` will be Promisified if not already promise. The Promise.reject in .catch is required though (however, alternatively you could `throw` the same "error object" instead)

Comment: Why would you return a promise AND have the caller pass in success and fail callbacks.  That makes no sense.  Just return the promise and let the caller use `.then()` and `.catch()` on it to specify success and fail handlers.  Also, your `.catch()` handler guarantees that the returned promise never rejects because it catches the reject and turns it into a resolve.  Plus, this looks way more complicated than required to just wrap a thin shell around `fetch()` to give it a little more default behavior.

Comment: @jfriend00 I hear you on the callback handlers, but wrapping Fetch allows us to handle errors in one place (i.e. unauthorized, etc.). Additionally, the wrapper applies some default headers that are universal to the application. Regarding your statement, 'return the promise' can you post an answer of what that would look like? That is what I'm trying to learn.

Comment: @JaromandaX You're saying the _inner_ `.catch` can throw an error and it will bubble up to the outer one? That makes sense and is more in line with how I would expect to write this.

Comment: I did not post an answer because your requirements for what this function needs to do are not clear.  Passing in both overridable callbacks and returning a promise leads to all sorts of confusing ways this could be used so I have no idea what the actual requirements are.

Comment: @jfriend00 This is a convenience function that takes care of setting up headers and other request info so the consumer doesn't have to deal with that. This should take care of error handling for the Fetch request. I want to return a Promise so the consumer can continue chaining functionality (instead of using callbacks).

Comment: Why are you passing in callbacks at all then?  It appears like you're trying to allow the caller to NOT use the promise and use plain callbacks instead.